# ImageMagick, Resizing images that don't scale horribly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I'm building an app where you can upload images, large resolution images (1000px+ width and height at times)

Issue is, I'm using the following to create a thumbnail with Rails/PaperClip:

:thumb => "100x75>"

What I want is for the image to always fill that dimension (assuming the image is at least that size.

But I don't want the image to scale and look squished. What's the right smart setting to keep thumbnails looking good in ImageMagick?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works pretty good for me:

```
:thumb => "100x75#"
```

The only problem is, you might not get every single detail in the thumb, but it's a good compromise IMO.